# Chrome headless screenshot on local machine

Tags: google-chrome, ember.js, lighthouse

I have a localhost website created with ember which is just working fine.

I want to use Lighthouse to get some metrics about the performance over time. Of course I want this to be in Chrome and headless. I installed Lighthouse using NPM and run the following command:

```
lighthouse http://localhost:4200 -chrome-flags='--headless'
```

When running above, I got the following error resulting in a question mark as a performance metric:

```
Chrome didn't collect any screenshots during the page load. Please make sure there is content visible on the page, and then try re-running Lighthouse. (SPEEDINDEX_OF_ZERO)
```

I tried running the dist folder of ember with the http-server package, but no differences in the result. The same error occurs.

When I run the test against google.com or against a website in our test environment I get a result back and not the error. When a colleague is running it on his local machine, no error occurs. Only difference we can find is he is running win8.1 and my machine is win10.

When I run Chrome without the headless flagg I also get a result, but I need it to work headless.

I'm using all the latest versions of Lighthouse, Chrome, Windows10, node. Also tried Chromium but no differences.

Hopefully someone got an idea

Comment: Certain features in chrome don't work when in headless mode, like devtools, this might be the same for lighthouse.

Comment: I know, running with network throttling is something what isnt working. But this wasnt the case, because it works on the machine of my colleague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week I tried again, still the same error. Now I tried again and it works. Nothing changed to my codebase and all apps, packs and so on are also the same version which I can see.

I don't know what fixed the issue, but it works now. Case closed.